# Generate samples to test against RegEx

Tags: c#, regex

I have a RegEx statement

```
 Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(?=.{8}$)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[,@#$])");
```

I want to test this by generating random words and letters that will be used to test against my expression. Only the valid ones will make it. All others will be discarded. Any suggestions on how to randomly generate this?

Comment: Look into Fuzz Testing strings in C# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzz_testing

Answer (score 1):

I solved my own problem. I used this code

```
var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789@#$";
var random = new Random();
var result = new string(
    Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 8)
              .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)])
              .ToArray());
```